# Hook works in literal phrase, but not when assigned to variable

Tags: j

Consider:

```
  x=.4 5 6 7
  i.# x
0 1 2 3
```

This is as expected.  The hook `#` acts upon the argument (the list `4 5 6 7`), returning its length, `4`, which is in turn passed to `i.`, and the numbers 0 through 3 are printed.

However, if instead I first assign the verb phrase to a variable, and *then* apply it to the same list, I get a different answer:

```
   y=.i.#
   y x
0
```

Why?

Comment: The issue here is some confusion of terminology. Your second example, `y=.i.#`, is indeed a *hook*, and is functioning [as *hook*s are defined](http://jar.ma/1VVP95). Your first example, `i.#x`, is **not** a hook, but a simple noun phrase, and is also operating as such noun phrases are defined. If you want the verbal equivalent of `i.#x`, then use `foo=:i.@:#` Note: it's best practice not to re-define `x` or `y` or `u` or `v`; if you must, do it locally, base it on the pre-existing value of the same name, and *retain the nameclass*, or you'll just confuse everyone reading your code.

Comment: hi @DanBron thanks for your comments.  on further investigation I think what is happening in the second case is that a fork is being used and the dyadic version of `i.` is assumed.  is there a way to force the monadic version and hence avoid the composition operator?

Comment: No, in the second version a *hook* is being used. A *fork* is composed of 3 verbs, a hook is composed of 2 verbs. You only have 2 verbs in your second example, `i.` and `#`, so what you're dealing with is a hook. Your further analysis is correct: hooks *always* invoke the dyadic valence of the left verb, regardless of whether the hook (a verb itself) is invoked monadically or dyadically. If you want a conjunction-less composition of `i.` and `#` (though ask yourself "why?"), then you must use the special-case "capped fork", or pseudo-fork, `[: i. #`. This use-case is its raison d'etre.

Comment: thank you!  if you want to add that as an answer i'll accept.  further i see you're a J enthusiast and i'm just starting to learn it.  if you have any favorite resources or advice for learning i'd appreciate that too

Comment: Cool. If I get time later, I'll add an answer. In the meantime, anyone else reading these comments is welcome and encouraged to post his own, based on my comments or not, attributing me or not. Also, since this is a very common pitfall when learning J, I'm sure there are existing answers on other questions which address it in detail. As for resources, my best friend, going on 20 years ago, when learning J, was simply experimenting in the REPL. But if you have a C- or C-like (e.g. Java) language background, check out [*J for C Programmers*](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/jforc/contents.htm).

Comment: @Jonah `(i. #) y` is a hook while `i. # y` simply evaluates arguments right to left. `v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 y` is equivalent to `v1 (v2 (v3 (v4 (v5 y))))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(i. #) y` is a hook while `i. # y` simply evaluates arguments right to left. `v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 y` is equivalent to `v1 (v2 (v3 (v4 (v5 y))))`

The issue here is some confusion of terminology. Your second example, `y =. i. #`, is indeed a *hook*, and is functioning [as *hooks* are defined](http://jar.ma/1VVP95). Your first example, `i. # x`, is not a hook, but a simple *noun phrase*, and is also operating as such *noun phrases* are defined. If you want the verbal equivalent of `i. # x`, then use `foo =: i. @: #`

In the second version a *hook* is being used. A *fork* is composed of 3 verbs, a *hook* is composed of 2 verbs. You only have 2 verbs in your second example, `i.` and `#`, so what you're dealing with is a *hook*. *Hooks* always invoke the dyadic valence of the left verb, regardless of whether the *hook* (a verb itself) is invoked monadically or dyadically.

If you want a conjunction-less composition of `i.` and `#` (though ask yourself "why?"), then you must use the special-case "capped fork", or pseudo-fork, `[: i. #`. This use-case is its raison d'etre.

Note: it's best practice not to re-define `x` or `y` or `u` or `v`; if you must, do it locally, base it on the pre-existing value of the same name, and retain the nameclass, or you'll just confuse everyone reading your code.

Acknowledgment: [Eelvex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/349708/eelvex) and [Dan Bron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2562182/dan-bron)'s comments have been answerified by pasting them above and edited ever so slightly.